# Get comma separated array from json array

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

**JS**

```
var arrSpecialInstructions = [];
arrSpecialInstructions.push("sder");
arrSpecialInstructions.push("vfgtr");
$.ajax(
{
    url: "/PetBooking/CreditCardBookingProcess/",
    data:
    {
        'arrSpecialInstructions': JSON.stringify(arrSpecialInstructions)
    },
    type: 'POST',
    success: function (data, status, xhr) {},
    error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {}
});
```

**Action method**

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult CreditCardBookingProcess(string arrSpecialInstructions)
{
    var specialInstructionsArray = arrSpecialInstructions.Split(',');
}
```

I just need to retrieve the comma separated string array.But it gives as below.How can I get just simple string array like this sder,vfgtr after splitting it.At this moment it's having lots of other characters.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to stringify just use `join()` :

```
data: { 'arrSpecialInstructions': arrSpecialInstructions.join() },
```

Comment: It says : Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Array] has no method 'split'

Comment: oh pardon me i meant join not split :/

Comment: Yep.It's working.Thanks a lot.But one thing,Can you tell me why 'stringify' is not working here ?

Comment: Technically it's working but you would need to parse the json on the server side to obtain the array. This way you can just do split like you wanted.